# Android WebView - Gives D/TilesManager: in log

Tags: android, mobile, webview

When run WebView , log console is as bellow, What is D/TilesManager? And how can avoid that?

```
D/TilesManager: Starting TG #0, 0xb9655000
02-17 08:47:10.035 18033-18333/edu.mobile D/TilesManager: Starting TG #0, 0xb96566a0
02-17 08:47:10.045 18033-18334/edu.mobile D/TilesManager: Starting TG #0, 0xb96548a0
02-17 08:47:10.045 18033-18335/edu.mobile D/TilesManager: Starting TG #0, 0xb9660c50
02-17 08:47:10.045 18033-18336/edu.mobile D/TilesManager: Starting TG #0, 0xb9662190
02-17 08:47:10.045 18033-18337/edu.mobile D/TilesManager: Starting TG #0, 0xb96636d0
02-17 08:47:10.045 18033-18338/edu.mobile D/TilesManager: Starting TG #0, 0xb9664c10
02-17 08:47:10.045 18033-18339/edu.mobile D/TilesManager: Starting TG #0, 0xb9666170
02-17 08:47:10.055 18033-18033/edu.mobile D/TilesManager: new EGLContext from framework: b9458070 
02-17 08:47:10.075 18033-18033/edu.mobile.tutoc.com.tutocmobile D/GLWebViewState: Reinit shader
02-17 08:47:10.225 18033-18033/edu.mobile D/GLWebViewState: Reinit transferQueue
```

Code in fragment

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_topic_details, container, false);
        wvTopicDetails = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.wv_topic_details);

        wvTopicDetails.setWebChromeClient(new WebViewChromeClient());
        wvTopicDetails.setWebViewClient(new WebViewNormalClient());
        wvTopicDetails.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        wvTopicDetails.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        wvTopicDetails.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wvTopicDetails.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);

        return view;
    }

 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        navigationListener.toggleToolbar(true);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            topicItem = (TopicItem)    bundle.getSerializable(AppConstants.PARA_NAME_TOPIC_ITEM);            
            wvTopicDetails.loadDataWithBaseURL("", topicItem.getHtmlString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are just debug messages that come from a component of WebView as it operates normally.  You can ignore them.  If you don't want to see any debug messages, change your logcat filter to stop displaying them.